# Is there a way to monitor the progress of removing files on Linux?

Tags: filesystems, rm

I have a directory with millions of files, and I'm deleting it by `rm -rf diretory_with_millions_of_files`. I can see the change in the usage of inode counts on the filesystem. But is there a more granular way to monitor its progress?